# Conditional CSS. Different Colors for different input text

Tags: css, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am using the below code to format the buttons. Is there a way to format "0" in black color and "x" in a different color in this Tic Tac Toe game played against computer.

```
input[type='button'] {
    border : 3px solid #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #FF0066;
    padding : 3px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Papyrus,fantasy;
}
```

Comment: Probably use `classes`?

Comment: Something like `.btn0{color:#444444}` and `.btnX{color:#0096D6}`

Answer (score 3):

Add a class to the button based on whether it's X or O, like this:

**CSS**

```
input[type=button].x {
    color: #000;
}

input[type=button].o {
    color: #f00;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="x">X</input>
```

Comment: Assigning classes won't help I believe , since the text is entered dynamically and there is no one fixed button for X , depends on the user which one he clicks. You can chk the page "www.acrosszero.org"

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as conditions in CSS. But you can always add classes to your boxes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isTac = false;
  $('.box').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('tic') && !$(this).hasClass('tac')) {
      $(this).addClass(isTac ? 'tac' : 'tic');
      isTac = !isTac;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tic-tac {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
}
.box {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.box.tic:after {
  content: 'X';
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 3px;
}
.box.tac:after {
  content: 'O';
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 2px;
}
.row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tic-tac">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box tic"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box tac"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```